# How to create a random matrix whose spectral radius $<1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a matrix size $n$, I want to produce a matrix $A$ with $\rho(A)<1$, which is not diagonal. Is there a way to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: What distribution on those matrices do you want? You could always generate a diagonal $\Lambda$ with $\rho(\Lambda)<1$ and output $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$ for a random $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy-to-apply idea: if every entry has absolute value less than $1/n$, then the spectral radius will be less than $1$.